# How to modify imported pdf graphics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdf

Is it possible to modify the thickness of lines in an imported pdf image using latex?

P.S. I have plots (vector graphics) in pdf format. I import them in latex and zoom into sum parts using `tikz` with `spy` library. I don't want the lines to become thicker in the magnified plot to be able to see more details. I decided to use a modified version of the plot with thin lines to zoom-in. However, I can't find a way to change the thickness of lines.

Comment: And what is the source of this `pdf`'s: are you compile it from `tikz`? export from `R`?.. or?

Comment: It is simple. I have a pdf file created by some other program, in may case a plot in Matlab. I import this image as as a graphics andI want to decrease the width of all the lines in the image. For example, I want to set all line ticknesses to 2 points. The reason as described above, is to be able to zoom in withouth making the lines thicker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really.

*In theory* you can parse the content stream of included PDFs with Lua code in the latest versions of LuaTeX and you could probably also modify the content stream (thus changing the line width), but I don't think anybody has tried that yet.

Comment: Actually you can but you also need to reset it afterwards to leave the remaining paths unaltered. But once you go into it that deep, better write a PDF parser anyway.

Comment: I am not specific about some paths/lines, hence there might be no need to parse the file rigorously. I want to reduce the thickness of all the lines and traces, everything visible, since my pdf only contains line drawings. There might be some keywords in the file to search and change their values blindly, unfortunately I don't know about pdf format. The question is that is there any package out there, for pdflatex, that can do some basic modifications on included/imported pdf graphics?

Comment: @Aydin: You really need a content stream parser (even a limited one), otherwise you're just poking more or less blindly.

Comment: Thanks Matrtin. I accept your answer "Not really"! It is good to know that what can't be done economically. Being unable to change the line tickness makes it difficult to zoom in/out vector graphics. It is different from the bitmap images, since for vector graphics, say maps or plots, people do not expect thicker lines when they zoom into an specific region.